# (Python) How can I add characters to a certain string in a set?

Tags: python

I have some ideas on how to do this and I don't really know how to approach it. I wrote up this code and it doesn't seem to work, mainly because I don't know how sets work. It's supposed to take a list and if any of the strings are matching it will take that string and make it plural then add it to a set.

```
    newSet = set()

    for i in lst:
        if lst.count(i) > 1:
            newSet.add(i)
            "s".join(newSet)
        else:
            newSet.add(i)

    return newSet
```

Comment: What do you think `"s".join(newSet)` does?

Comment: I'm very new to coding but I think it adds characters to strings? idk man I am very confused lol

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation for `str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Comment: It's better to provide some sample inputs and desired outputs first.

Comment: Here is the input: ["cow", "pig", "cow", "cow"] And this is what the output looks like: {'cow', 'pig'} Since the string cow appears more than once it should be plural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `str` is immutable.
We can assign `name = 'cow'` and then
talk about `name + 's'`, but that plural
string is a *separate* string object.
Appending `'s'` has no effect on the first string.

Better to populate the set with what you want
from the get go, rather than populating it
and then changing your mind.
That way there's no need to remove singular
when you add plural to the set.

cf [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

animals = Counter(['cow', 'pig', 'cow', 'pig', 'sheep'])
print({name if count == 1 else f'{name}s'
       for name, count in animals.items()})
```

EDIT

The [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) computes `name + 's'`.

The [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-set-comprehension) computes this:

```
s = set()
for name, count in animals.items():
    s.add(name)  # or if you prefer, an expression that pluralizes
print(s)
```

Comment: ahh thank you very much it works. Could you also explain how it works? I've seen these 1 liner for loops and they confuse me.